# What is the purpose of Keras custom objects when creating custom layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Looking at layers implementations of third parties, like `tensorflow_addons`, I see that each layer is being registered as a custom object.
For example, you can see the use of the wrapper `register_custom_keras_object` call [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/layers/normalizations.py#L26).

This wrapper uses the function [`tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_custom_objects) to do the registering.

My question, is why should this be done for any custom layers? What is the benefit of registering the layer as a custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this allows you to then to refer to your custom object **via string**. You see this with keras default objects all the time. For example:

```py
# You can either compile a model with the Adam optimizer like this
model.compile(optimizer='adam', ...)

# or like this
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=adam, ...)
```

---

Taken from the [definition of `custom_object_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L76):

Code within a `with` statement will be able to access custom objects by name. Changes to global custom objects persist within the enclosing `with` statement. At end of the `with` statement, global custom objects are reverted to state at beginning of the `with` statement.

Example:   Consider a custom object `MyObject`

```py
with custom_object_scope({'MyObject':MyObject}):
    layer = Dense(..., kernel_regularizer='MyObject')
    # save, load, etc. will recognize custom object by name
```

Defined as

```py
def custom_object_scope(*args)
```

Arguments:

`*args`: Variable length list of dictionaries of name, class pairs to add to custom objects.

Comment: Is that one of the things it serves? Or the only advantage as registering an object as custom is being able to call it by a string name ?

Comment: as far as I know, this is the only thing that it does

Comment: Doesn't seem so useful to me, accepted the answer though :)